# infinite loop in siftDown method for a heap using linked nodes

Tags: java, heap, nodes, infinite-loop

In my siftDown method for my heap, I'm getting an infinite loop I believe that is being caused by my if(current.isLeaf()) line. Can anyone help me so that I can get Node n down to where it becomes a leaf or when it stops being smaller than its children?

```
public void siftDown(Node<V> n) {
    Node<V> current = n;
    boolean notDone = true;
    while (notDone) {
        if (!current.isLeaf()) {
            current = n;
            if ((current.data.compareTo(current.left.data) < 0)
                    && (current.left.data.compareTo(current.right.data) >= 0)) {
                swapValues(current, current.left);
                current = current.left;
            } else if ((current.data.compareTo(current.right.data) < 0)
                    && (current.right.data.compareTo(current.left.data) > 0)) {
                swapValues(current, current.right);
                current = current.right;
                if (current.isLeaf()) {
                    notDone = false;
                }
            }
        } else {
            notDone = false;
        }    
    }    
}    

public void swapValues(Node<V> x, Node<V> y) {     
    V temp = x.data;
    x.data = y.data;
    y.data = temp;
}

public boolean isLeaf() { //inside my node class
    if (left == null && right == null)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Comment: you are overwriting your current node with n inside of the loop (current = n), so every time you descend the tree you end up going back to the beginning.

Comment: Thank you! I cannot believe I didn't see that. I must be getting tired.